# SSL issues after migration to Apache 2.4.37 from 2.4.7 using ppa:ondrej/apache2

Tags: 14.04, apache2.4, mod-ssl

I have an annoying issue after migrating to Apache 2.4.37 using [`ppa:ondrej/apache2`](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2?field.series_filter=trusty). After the change I've got a lot of `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` while accessing my sites.

The effect is that when having a site that has some ajax script that keeps checking for some data periodically, every second request, sometime more keeps returning the error mentioned above. The same happens when refreshing a site - it keeps being in loop 'insecure - secure - insecure'.

[EDIT]
Whenever that happens, there are no errors in the log regarding that matter. Not to mention, that it happens globally - all sites served from the server have this issue at the same moment, for similar period of time.

The request on browser look like this:

[devtools request list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANzVQ.png)

For certification on my server I'm using Let'sEncrypt `certbot`, also in every SSL enabled vhost I have included the [`options-ssl-apache.conf`](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/blob/master/certbot-apache/certbot_apache/options-ssl-apache.conf) provided by Let'sEncrypt.

I will point out, that my **vhost confs did not change after the update, nor the cert files used by the sites**. - the issue does not happen on 2.4.7, only when updated to 2.4.37.

#### Wireshark logs

```
Time            Source          Target          Protocol    Info
9.759740        local_ip        server_ip       TCP         60485 → 443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=256 Len=1 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
9.886868        server_ip       local_ip        TCP         443 → 60485 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=2 Win=653 Len=0 SLE=1 SRE=2
11.082160       local_ip        server_ip       TLSv1.2     Ignored Unknown Record
11.209445       server_ip       local_ip        TCP         443 → 60485 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=966 Win=668 Len=0
11.209446       server_ip       local_ip        TLSv1.2     Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unexpected Message)
11.209446       server_ip       local_ip        TCP         443 → 60485 [FIN, ACK] Seq=8 Ack=966 Win=668 Len=0
11.209495       local_ip        server_ip       TCP         60485 → 443 [ACK] Seq=966 Ack=9 Win=256 Len=0
11.209645       local_ip        server_ip       TLSv1.2     Encrypted Alert
11.209917       local_ip        server_ip       TCP         60485 → 443 [FIN, ACK] Seq=989 Ack=9 Win=256 Len=0
11.336928       server_ip       local_ip        TCP         443 → 60485 [RST] Seq=9 Win=0 Len=0
11.336991       server_ip       local_ip        TCP         443 → 60485 [RST] Seq=9 Win=0 Len=0
72.078422       local_ip        server_ip       TCP         60691 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
72.209323       server_ip       local_ip        TCP         443 → 60691 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
72.209390       local_ip        server_ip       TCP         60691 → 443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=0
72.209587       local_ip        server_ip       TLSv1.2     Client Hello
72.340476       server_ip       local_ip        TCP         443 → 60691 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=518 Win=30336 Len=0
72.341920       server_ip       local_ip        TLSv1.2     Server Hello, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
72.342281       local_ip        server_ip       TLSv1.2     Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
72.343018       local_ip        server_ip       TLSv1.2     Application Data
72.473941       server_ip       local_ip        TCP         443 → 60691 [ACK] Seq=149 Ack=1525 Win=32256 Len=0
72.510918       server_ip       local_ip        TLSv1.2     Application Data
72.552329       local_ip        server_ip       TCP         60691 → 443 [ACK] Seq=1525 Ack=935 Win=64512 Len=0
117.510566      local_ip        server_ip       TCP         [TCP Keep-Alive] 60691 → 443 [ACK] Seq=1524 Ack=935 Win=64512 Len=1
117.641439      server_ip       local_ip        TCP         [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] 443 → 60691 [ACK] Seq=935 Ack=1525 Win=32256 Len=0 SLE=1524 SRE=1525
132.080054      local_ip        server_ip       TLSv1.2     Application Data
132.211048      server_ip       local_ip        TCP         443 → 60691 [ACK] Seq=935 Ack=2489 Win=34176 Len=0
132.211049      server_ip       local_ip        TLSv1.2     Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unexpected Message)
132.211049      server_ip       local_ip        TCP         443 → 60691 [FIN, ACK] Seq=942 Ack=2489 Win=34176 Len=0
132.211148      local_ip        server_ip       TCP         60691 → 443 [ACK] Seq=2489 Ack=943 Win=64512 Len=0
132.211288      local_ip        server_ip       TLSv1.2     Encrypted Alert
132.211496      local_ip        server_ip       TCP         60691 → 443 [FIN, ACK] Seq=2512 Ack=943 Win=64512 Len=0
132.342025      server_ip       local_ip        TCP         443 → 60691 [RST] Seq=943 Win=0 Len=0
132.342255      server_ip       local_ip        TCP         443 → 60691 [RST] Seq=943 Win=0 Len=0
```

Comment: Tail the Apache logs as you attempt to access.  It sounds to me like you've got some other config problem lying around, or a redirect loop in the config for a specific underlying site.

Comment: I do not get any errors in apache logs at all, even when disabling all sites but one, the issue still happens and having LogLevel=debug. I've added wireshark logs above.

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing issues with my SSL enabled VirtualHosts which are running RT4 ticketing systems. I upgraded to apache2 2.4.37-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 and openssl 1.1.1-3+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+3.

For me the situation is as follows. Remotely, I can access the website running on the server just fine using a browser on my local machine. But when I use the command line tools on the server itself to access the tickets, then the command times out and I get to see an error. Also, the rt-mailgate program which is used to feed new tickets is also failing with an error. Unfortunately, I don't see a lot of errors appearing in the logfiles when I use the debug level :-(

If I reconfigure the setup and disable the SSL (so running via http instead of via https), then these scripts run fine again. So the SSL-layer looks to be the culprit...

Maybe this is related to the bug ticket "Login with client cert times out" at
On https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1803689 (at least the combo apache2/openssl versions are the same).